# Return an Object from BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am dithering an image in a BackgroundWorker thread and need to update the UI after the image is done processing.  The image I need to update exists in the same class as the DitherWorker.  How do I pass the BitmapSource so that the noted error does not occur?

```
public void DitherWorker()
{
    double scalebox = Double.Parse(myWindow.scaleBox.Text);
    int slider = (int)myWindow.convolutionBiasSlider.Value;
    BitmapSource final = null;
    ditherobj output = new ditherobj(scalebox, originalImage, slider);//.Get_Halftone();

    worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

    worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs args)
    {
        ditherobj dob = (ditherobj)args.Argument;
        Binarize bn = new Binarize(dob.scalebox, dob.localbms, dob.slider);
        BitmapSource bms = (BitmapSource)bn.Get_Halftone();
        final = bms;
        args.Result = new ditherobj(0,null,0,bms);
    };

    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        ditherobj dob = (ditherobj)args.Result;
        image1.Source = dob.localbms; //ERROR. The calling thread cannot access this object because another thread owns it

        myWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            myWindow.activityBar.IsBusy = false;
        }));
    };

    worker.RunWorkerAsync((ditherobj)output);
}

public class ditherobj
    {
        public double scalebox;
        public BitmapSource localbms;
        public BitmapImage localbmi;
        public int slider;

        public ditherobj(double scalebox, BitmapImage localbmi, int slider, BitmapSource bms = null)
        {
            this.scalebox = scalebox;
            this.slider = slider;
            if (bms == null)
            {
                BitmapImage test = localbmi.Clone();
                localbms = (BitmapSource)test;
            }
            else
                localbms = bms;
        }
    }
```

Problem solved.  The BitmapSource must be frozen in the background thread before being passed.  Here is the final comented code:

```
BackgroundWorker worker;
    public void DitherWorker()
    {
        double scalebox = Double.Parse(myWindow.scaleBox.Text); //get values from UI for the job
        int slider = (int)myWindow.convolutionBiasSlider.Value;
        DitherSettings output = new DitherSettings(scalebox, originalImage, slider); //create holder object to be passed to BackgroundWorker
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {

            DitherSettings ds = (DitherSettings)args.Argument;  //cast argument as our holder object
            Binarize bn = new Binarize(ds.scalebox, ds.localbms, ds.slider); //create object to do our work
            BitmapSource bms = (BitmapSource)bn.Get_Halftone(); //do work
            bms.Freeze(); //freeze resulting BitmapSource so it can be utilized elsewhere
            args.Result = new DitherSettings(0,null,0,bms);  //create new object with resulting BitmapSource

        };

        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            DitherSettings ds = (DitherSettings)args.Result;  //get object with our BitmapSource

            if (image1.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                this.image1.Source = ds.localbms; //update class image

            myWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                myWindow.activityBar.IsBusy = false; //Update UI control
            }));
        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync((DitherSettings)output);

    }

    public class DitherSettings
    {
        public double scalebox;
        public BitmapSource localbms;
        public BitmapImage localbmi;
        public int slider;

        public DitherSettings(double scalebox, BitmapImage localbmi, int slider, BitmapSource bms = null)
        {
            this.scalebox = scalebox;
            this.slider = slider;
            if (bms == null)
                localbms = (BitmapSource)localbmi;
            else
                localbms = bms;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `ditherobj`?  The concept of thread ownership and ownership transfers isn't core to .NET; if this is a third-party library, which library are you using?  Or is this your class?

Comment: A simple object to hold the values being passed around.  Edited the post to show this.

Comment: Why is the `ditherobj` class/struct not named `DitherSettings`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the `Freeze()` function on the `BitmapSource` when you are still on the background thread.

This makes the object immutable, and can therefore be used on the main thread.

[Learn here more about freezable wpf objects.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx) The page discusses a lot of other aspects of Freezables, but it also explicitly states: "A frozen Freezable can also be shared across threads, ...". This ability built in WPF to build GUI elements (such as bitmaps) on background threads is the #1 underadvertized WPF feature if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

`BitmapSource.Clone()` may be of some use if you want to copy the object.

`Dispatcher.CheckAccess()` should be called prior to setting image1.Source.

Comment: Great, added CheckAccess() before setting the image.